# Waiting for another process during a DB transaction

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, transactions

I have an application which stores files in AWS S3 and files metadata in a MySQL. Each operation (upload, update, delete) typically needs to update both S3 and DB.

How to make such an action “atomic”?  Can I wrap it to a DB transaction, which will wait until the S3 action finishes? 
Example:

```
DB transaction start
Make an S3 action (can take a few seconds)
Make a DB action(s)
DB transaction commit
```

Currently I call the S3 action out of the DB transaction, because I tend to keep the DB transactions as short as possible so that they do not lock the DB, which of course makes it open for potential data inconsistency in a case the DB action is not successful.

What would you recommend? Can I use the suggested approach or is there some other way of doing it? I was considering XA transactions, AWS queues; I tried to do some research but surprisingly did not find anything useful.

My server-side technology is php.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we do (not exactly S3 and DB) but a similar distributed commit:

- Make an S3 Action
- DB transaction start
- Perform DB Action

  - If DB Action throws an exception, revert* the action in S3
  - If the DB Action succeeds, commit and done.

revert - could be a bit involved depending on the original action was an insert or an update.

Comment: Thank you TJ. This is actually how I am doing it right now. However I am not satisfied with it because something wrong can still happen between the DB exception and the S3 revert; or when the DB dies after the S3 action. In both these cases we have an inconsistent state.

Comment: These are the perils of distributed transactions. Cleanup jobs are used to take care of some of the things that you mentioned. Get(key) succeeds only if attributes from both the sources is available and so on.

Comment: I still hope the IT world is not so cruel and there is the silver bullet :)

Comment: I thought about your answer and I would interpret it this way:  
1. Keep the things simple.  
2. A failure will happen, prepare for it.  
3. Order actions in such a way that the failure will leave the inconsistent data “invisible”: user will see it as a failure and will repeat the action; the application will ignore the inconsistent data.  
4. A cleanup job will get rid of the failed transactions remains.  
Actually, I quite like it and I think that it could work. Thank you TJ!